Overflow while performing addition in one way and getting correct output in other way but why?
I am writing code and it has a line where a, b, c, d are integers,
int a, b, c, d;
long long sum = a + b + c + d;

I get an overflow error, but after referring answer and modifying the sum as below lines which is in answer I didn't get any problem:
long long sum = a;
sum += b;
sum += c;
sum += d;

For this line I get correct result. What is the difference?

The first addition a + b +c+ d involves only ints, so it is performed using ints. The second version involves a long long, so the value is converted first, and added later.

It's about timing. In the first case the conversion to long long is done after the addition (so the addition overflows). In the second case the conversion to long long is done before any addition, reducing the chance of overflow.

The first is as-if int temp = a + b + c + d; long long sum = temp;

See Implicit type conversion rules in C++ operators which explains what happens when different types are involved for operators.

In the first case the expression:
a + b + c + d

Contains only ints and therefore no conversion is done and the calculation is done in ints (with potential overflow).
The fact that the result is used to initialize a long long is not relevant because the expression is evaluated regardless of the initialization following it (the same would apply if it was an assignment instead of an initialization).
Only the result is converted when the initialization of sum is performed.
In the second case lines like:
sum += b;

Are actually:
sum = sum + b;

And sum + b is an expression containing both an int and a long long.
Therefore in order to evaluate it b is converted to long long and the overflow you had in the first case is not happening.
A side note:
In the posted code a,b, c and d are not initialized.
I assume that in your actual code they are.

int sum = a + b + c + d does not involve any assignment.   It computes a + b + c + d as an int (like you say, that may overflow) but then initialises sum with the result of converting that computed sum to long long.    That initialisation may (syntactically) involve the = token, but is not an assignment expression.

@Peter you are right of course. I fixed it now.
